# Why does the energy density of the gluon field have any connection to electric or magnetic field strength?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In the video [Revealing The Origin of Mass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qJ0o4U63aw) Professor Derek Leinweber gives the formula for energy density of the gluon field as simply the electric field strength squared plus the magnetic field strength squared, over the range of the 8 gluons.  Why is there any connection between gluon energy density and electric or magnetic field strength.  Quarks and electrons have electric charge and thus magnetic fields, but gluons only have color charge or chromoelectric charge, which is not  the same as normal electric charge.  What is the connection to the electric charge that makes Leinweber's formula appropriate?

Comment: *Chromoelectric and Chromomagnetic fields

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux  According to this answer, chromooelectric fields are very different from normal electric fields:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/426507/what-are-chromoelectric-and-chromomagnetic-fields    So can you provide me something that ties them to the electric field strength in a way that makes the formulas suitable?

Comment: They are defined the same way: through the curvature of the gauge field. The difference resides in the difference in their gauge group. Have you read the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon_field#Introduction) entry on the gluon field?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the video - the "electric" and "magnetic" fields here are supposed to be the chromo-* fields. There is no "connection to electric charge".

Comment: @ACuriousMind is there some way to see that he is referring to chromo fields in the video?

Comment: Really nice question, as you see from @ACuriousMind's comment, the video is referring to the chromo electric and magnetic fields of the gluons as simply saying "electric and magnetic field of the gluons", thus the video is confusing. "electric and magnetic" here only refers to the similarities with the electric and magnetic field's of EM charges, but this is rather about the strong interaction, and the gluon's color fields.

Comment: Thanks very much guys